# Position of Calendar in DateTimePicker Control

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I am using dateTimePicker control of .Net framework 4.0 using C# and want it to behave a bit differently than its default behavior. After clicking on the calendar button, in default behavior calendar is shown in the bottom of the control. I want to modify it so that the calendar appears on top of the dateTimePicker control in windows forms application.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The tags should have included either ASp.net / wpf / winform

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have tried something like this and manually calculate the position? http://www.viblend.com/forum/d_postst145_Open-DateTimePicker-s-Popup-in-code.aspx

Comment: The problem with manually setting the control is that all of the control is shifted to new place. I just want to move the calendar that pops up after pressing the calendar button on control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `DateTimePicker` class from `System.Windows.Forms` then you will find four properties named `Right`,`Left`,`Top`,`Bottom`. Using this properties you can set the distance of your calender control in pixels from the corresponding margin of your container's client area. You can also set the `Width` property.

For more about the properties, check this - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: These properties apply to the control itself, I want to move the calendar popup.

Comment: There is no way found to control the popup position. For ASP.NET, there are some ways around. But Winforms doesn't allow to do that.